# Digital Compass and Magnetic Declination Angle

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-flux, compass

[image: Magnetic Declination]

I have a digital compass of HMC5883L and I want to measure orientation with it. The doubt that arise is about the magnetic declination angle. From the definition of declination angle, it is the the offset angle of Magnetic North from True North.

Therefore if I happened to be on a location which the declination angle is equal to zero. That means the angle that I measured with the compass should be an angle with relative to True North?
If the declination angle is positive, I should subtract the measured angle with the declination angle?

I tried to find use the digital compass to control the direction of a drone. I plan to control the direction with bearing calculation of two coordinates and use the digital compass to control the drone orientation. But I could not obtain a reliable result

Is it because the magnetic field line at my location appeared to be horizontal and instead of vertical? I remembered that my bearing calculation was made with a normal Cartesian XY axis.

**FYI: I happen to be on the Borneo Island, the place marked with a blue cross on the map.**

Comment: The magnetic lines also are not horizontal. In other words, the magnetic lines may travel through the surface of earth, rather than be parallel to the surface. The angle varies with location.

Comment: You meant the magnetic inclination?

Comment: Yes. Magnetic inclination.

Comment: With declination=0 there is no offset and magnetic north points to true north.  Your concept is right but I suspect you have messed up the coordinate calculation. What grid are you using for your coordinates? WGS84 lat long will need addition all correction... Add grid details to the question.

Comment: @mkeith dip has no effect on bearing, it just messes with a physical needle if you're not using a global compass.

Comment: I am not sure with what kind of grid which I used. I extracted my path's coordinates with google map and my current coordinates is extracted with GPS. The bearing calculation was made based on great circle concept. 
But WGS84 sounds interesting. Can u talk it in detail?

Comment: @PaulUszak Dip has MAJOR effect on bearing if the sensor is not level. High quality binnacle compasses for navigation are ballasted so that they remain level. Some handheld navigation compasses are designed for specific regions of the world, and will tilt very noticeably if they are used in other regions. With handheld fluxgate compasses, you are supposed to hold them level when in use.

Comment: @mkeith That's not the dip I meant...

Comment: Yes but my fear is that if your compass sensor is working correctly which should be easily verifiable, then this discussion will go off topic into navigational calculations.  Is your sensor working correctly when you walk with it?  Have you tested it alongside your GPS compass or a real one?

Comment: Well, my point was that if the OP is not taking account of whether the sensor is level, dip can foul everything up very badly.

Comment: I did test the digital compass with the compass apps on android phone.The result seemed fine so I think it should not be the compass sensor issue. I think the current issue that I have is the algorithm of the compass sensor.

Comment: Okay so progress :-)    If you have an interfacing /data interpretation issue with the sensor, it might be worthwhile asking a second question focused specifically on the sensor and micro controller.